# native query returns results on h2 but not in jpa repository

Tags: sql, spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity for a user.

```
data class User(
    @Id
    var userId: UUID,
    val orgId: UUID,

    @ManyToMany
    var representatives: MutableList<User>
)
```

The tables for this are as follows:

```
USER                        USER_REPRESENTATIVES
  --USER_ID                    --USER_USER_ID  
  --ORG_ID                     --REPRESENTATIVES_USER_ID
```

A user can have many representatives and can be a representative for another user themselves. I wanted to create a query that would get me a list of users whom are being represented by my current user.

In my h2 console when I use the following query I am able to achieve what I want with the following query:

```
SELECT USER_USER_ID FROM USER_REPRESENTATIVES
            WHERE EXISTS ( 
            SELECT USER_ID FROM USER 
            WHERE USER_REPRESENTATIVES.REPRESENTATIVES_USER_ID = USER.USER_ID)
```

However when I try actually running this in my jpa repository I am getting nothing back from the call itself. Here is the code I am using in my repository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT USER_USER_ID FROM USER_REPRESENTATIVES " +
            "WHERE EXISTS ( " +
            "SELECT USER_ID FROM USER " +
            "WHERE USER_REPRESENTATIVES.REPRESENTATIVES_USER_ID = USER.USER_ID)",
            nativeQuery = true)
    fun getUserRepresentativeFor(): MutableList<UUID>
```

What am I doing wrong in the spring/kotlin side of things that is making me receive nothing when I try calling that function?

Comment: If you want to retrieve information linked to a given user, then your query at least needs to have that given user as parameter. It doesn't have any parameter. Don't you simply want `user.representatives`? If you want the inverse, why don't you make it a bidirectional association?